# Proxy arp and 1:1 NAT

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, arp

I have a Linux router with 2 NICs doing masquerade from network `192.168.0.0/24` to an ADSL router.

```
users <----> NIC A [router] NIC B <----> INTERNET
```

Now I'm experimenting with proxy arp on the NIC A to intercept all the IP requests in the network.

I have a pool of addresses in the `192.168.0.0/24` network for this users.

How can I translate, say`the IP`10.0.0.64`to`192.168.0.64` in order to grant it internet access?

I have already tried SNAT - DNAT, even I have written a NFQUEUE app to spoof the IP address with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ip_forward enabled?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To enable it immediately:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To enable it permanently:

```
echo "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```